# How to implement automatic notifications in Flutter using bluetooth?

Tags: flutter

I'm developing an app that can send requests to a device and also receive data from the device. I can connect to the device, discover both the TX and RX characteristics and send the request but I'm stuck in getting the data back from the device. I believe I have to utilize the use of:

```
await characteristic.setNotifyValue(true);
characteristic.value.listen((value) {
    // do something with new value
});
```

I have this code for connecting, discovering characteristics and sending data.

```
class _DashboardScreenState extends State<DashboardScreen> {
  final String TxCharacteristic = "6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e";
  final String RxCharacteristic = "6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e";
  final String Blufruit_UUIDLC = "[6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e]";
  final String Blufruit_UUID = "[6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E]";

  FlutterBlue flutterBlue = FlutterBlue.instance;
  StreamSubscription<ScanResult> scanSubScription;

  BluetoothDevice targetDevice;
  BluetoothCharacteristic RxtargetCharacteristic;
  BluetoothCharacteristic TxtargetCharacteristic;

  String connectionText = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startScan();
  }

  startScan() {
    setState(() {
      connectionText = "Start Scanning";
      print("scanning");
    });

    scanSubScription = flutterBlue.scan().listen((scanResult) {
      print("found something");
      print(scanResult.advertisementData.serviceUuids.toString());
      if (scanResult.advertisementData.serviceUuids.toString() ==
          Blufruit_UUID) {
        print('DEVICE found');
        stopScan();
        setState(() {
          connectionText = "Found Target Device";
        });

        targetDevice = scanResult.device;
        connectToDevice();
      }
    }, onDone: () => stopScan());
  }

  stopScan() {
    scanSubScription?.cancel();
    scanSubScription = null;
  }

//  await targetDevice.setNotifyValue(characteristic, true);
//  device.onValueChanged(characteristic).listen((value) {
//    print(value);
//  });

  connectToDevice() async {
    if (targetDevice == null) return;

    setState(() {
      connectionText = "Device Connecting";
    });

    await targetDevice.connect();
    print('DEVICE CONNECTED');
    setState(() {
      connectionText = "Device Connected";
    });

//    TurnOnNotifications();
    discoverServices();
  }

  disconnectFromDevice() {
    if (targetDevice == null) return;

    targetDevice.disconnect();

    setState(() {
      connectionText = "Device Disconnected";
    });
  }

  discoverServices() async {
    if (targetDevice == null) return;

    List<BluetoothService> services = await targetDevice.discoverServices();
    services.forEach((service) {
      print(service.uuid.toString());
      if (service.uuid.toString() == "6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e") {
        service.characteristics.forEach((characteristic) {
          if (characteristic.uuid.toString() == TxCharacteristic) {
            print("connected to Tx: ");
            print(characteristic.uuid.toString());
            TxtargetCharacteristic = characteristic;
            setState(() {
              connectionText = "All Ready with ${targetDevice.name}";
            });
          }
          if (characteristic.uuid.toString() == RxCharacteristic) {
            print("connected to Rx: ");
            print(characteristic.uuid.toString());
            RxtargetCharacteristic = characteristic;
            setState(() {
              connectionText = "All Ready with ${targetDevice.name}";
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

//  _setNotification(BluetoothCharacteristic c) async {
//    if (c.isNotifying) {
//      await targetDevice.setNotifyValue(c, false);
//      // Cancel subscription
//      valueChangedSubscriptions[c.uuid]?.cancel();
//      valueChangedSubscriptions.remove(c.uuid);
//    } else {
//      await targetDevice.setNotifyValue(c, true);
//      // ignore: cancel_subscriptions
//      final sub = device.onValueChanged(c).listen((d) {
//        String x = "";
//        d.forEach((f) => x += String.fromCharCode(f));
//        Response = x;
//        setState(() {
//          print('onValueChanged $x');
//        });
//      });
//      // Add to map
//      valueChangedSubscriptions[c.uuid] = sub;
//    }
//    setState(() {});
//  }

  writeData(String data) {
    if (TxtargetCharacteristic == null) return;

    List<int> bytes = utf8.encode(data);
    TxtargetCharacteristic.write(bytes);
    bytes.clear();
  }
```